# Setting a static member from dot-sourced file

Tags: powershell, static-members, dot-source

While getting the value of a static member from inside a dot-sourced ps1 file always works, setting a static member seems inconsistent.

test.ps1:

```
class A
{
    static $val
    A()
    {
        [A]::val = "empty"
    }
}

$A = [A]::new()

write-host $([A]::val)

[A]::val = "test"

. .\test2.ps1

write-host $([A]::val)
```

test2.ps1

```
[A]::val = "val"
```

Console output:

```
empty
test
```

Console output I expected:

```
empty
val
```

So, I added a write-host to test2.ps1:

```
[A]::val = "val"

write-host $([A]::val)
```

And ran it again:

```
empty
val
val
```

Okay, I say to myself.
I remove the write-host from test2.ps1 and I get another unexpected console output:

```
empty
val
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Every test I tried so far produces "empty" followed by "val".  I'm using PS 5.1, both in VSCode and stand alone.  What version are you using and are you using VSCode?

Comment: same for me. im unable to replicate this on 7.4.0-preview.2 // did you try starting a fresh powershell session ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Santiago Squarzon, I just had to restart my code editor (VSCode) and the terminal I was executing the scripts in to start a new PSSession. Before I did that though, I found this way to circumvent the issue ;;

*test.ps1*

```
...
$x = ""

. .\test2.ps1

[A]::val = $x
...
```

*test2.ps1*

```
$x = "val"
```